# Flask CLI commands and arguments

Tags: python, flask, python-click, flask-cli

How do you let a Flask CLI command accept an argument?

Flask seems to customise the Click Group object, so this doesn't work:

```
@app.cli.command()
@app.cli.argument('email')
def user_info(email):
    ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`@app.cli.command` is only to tell the `click` about this `user_info`. If you want the arguments and other click functionality please use click as well.

```
@app.cli.command()
@click.option('--email')
def user_info(email):
    ...
```

Comment: `import click`  # Click is a simple Python module inspired by the stdlib optparse to make
    writing command line scripts fun. Unlike other modules, it's based
    around a simple API that does not come with too much magic and is
    composable.